# Cancel blocking activities in ELSA

Tags: c#, triggers, signals, elsa-workflows

I have 3 blocking activities sitting in parallel all waiting to be triggered. I'd like to cancel the other 2 when one is triggered (stop the other 2 from expecting a signal once one has been triggered), like this:

[workflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOeFR.png)

How can I do that in code? Say, after the Join activity, I have another activity that will cancel the other two that were not triggered. I don't want to use the Finish activity because that will stop the whole workflow. The reason I want to do this is because after one of the signals has been triggered the workflow resumes and if another signal is triggered it goes back to execute from where the signal is triggered. I do not want it to go back after one has been triggered.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing site. You have to show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging and discovered that the issue was on my end.

**Signal 1** is a custom blocking activity. Inside the `OnExecuteAsync` method there is a condition that returns `Done()`. So in this case the activity does not get suspended and wait for a trigger.

So, to fix that I added the line:
`context.WorkflowInstance.ScheduledActivities.Clear();` before `return Done();`